# Calculating Sums Of Maths

Tags: logarithms

I was wondering whether I got the correct answer. I'm supposed to solve by logs and get the exact value of x using my calculator. My question:

$9^{x -5} = 2^{x - 8}$

Comment: Do you mean $$6^{x-1}=4^{x-1}$$?

Comment: Ah yes, that's right. Just that I haven't got the grasp of the syntax yet.

Comment: The image says $6^{x-2}=4^{x-1}$  That's not what written in the question.

Comment: The answer you link to has a different exponent on the left hand.

Comment: from the user's notes, there's a typo. the equation should be $6^{x-2}=4^{x-1}$.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that. It's $6^{x -2} = 4^{x - 1}$ As mentioned by @Lacramioara

Comment: That looks right to me.

Comment: Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Alright, thank you all. Much appreciated. Also, thanks for that tutorial. It will be useful. Thanks again for those who commented.

Comment: Replace the value of $x$ you found in the original equation to test if it is the solution.

Comment: @N74 Completely missed that. Thanks for that tip. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

$$6^{x-2}=4^{x-1}\to(2^{x-2})(3^{x-2})=2^{2x-2}$$
$$\to3^{x-2}=2^{x}$$

---

We take logs so that:
$$x=\log_{2}{3^{x-2}}$$
$$\to x=(x-2)\log_2{3}$$

Then use an iteration:

$$x_{n+1}=(x_n-2)\log_2{3}$$

Plugging in values proves this iterate diverges.

---

We can also take logs for:
$$(x-2)=\log_3{2^x}$$
$$\to x=x\log_3{2}+2$$
and use the iteration:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n\log_3{2}+2, x_0=1$$
We get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\approx 5.419022583...$$
and so this is a solution. The divergence of the first iterate shows that this is the only solution.

Comment: Didn't see your answer hidden behind the link. Looks like you got it right.

Comment: Nice way of going about it. Thanks for this. I will keep this in mind next time I have an exam. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's a very simple way to find non-exact solutions to tough equations like these. Simply rearrange them into the form $x=f(x)$ for some $f(x)$ (there are always multiple ways to do this) and use $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ to iterate. You'll easily see by calculation which ones converge or diverge.

Answer (score 1):

So you will get $$(x-2)\ln(6)=(x-1)\ln(4)$$
you will get
$$x(\ln(6)-\ln(4))=2\ln(6)-\ln(4)$$